# How can exp(-M t) M be diagonalized

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $M$ is a $n \times n$ matrix, 
having $n$ positive eigenvalues and $n$ independent eigenvectors
($M$ is not necessarily symmetric).

Is it possible to diaginalize $A=exp(-Mt) M$  ?

For example SVD can work, so that
$A= U D V^T$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix,
but then $U$ depends on t.

Any other suggestion using matrices $U,V$ which are independent on $t$?

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite see what SVD has to do with this, since you claim to be interested in *diagonalisation*, i.e. finding an eigenvector basis, and not in singular vectors. Anyways, by identity $e^{PAP^{-1}}=Pe^AP^{-1}$, any eigenvector basis for $A$ is also an eigenvector basis for $e^{A}$. Therefore you can just pick a basis that diagonalises $M$, and it will automatically diagonalise $-Mt$ and $e^{-Mt}$ for all $t$, and thus $e^{-Mt}M$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. May I add- is it possible to diagonalize this matrix using unitary matrices, i.e, U exp{A t} A V^T, where U and V are unitary matrices?